# SEF urls are not takinf alias.html name of menu item in joomla1.5

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-sef-urls

I have two menu links of my component com_listing whose links are as follows

1. index.php?option=com_listing&view=catlist&Itemid=134
2. index.php?option=com_listing&view=catlist&Itemid=135

Both menu item have component menu item specific parameters of parent category and child category .by setting these two parameter values each link will show different data although they are the same link but their menu item specific  parameter in menu item is different.

They are working fine and showing different data for their links

1. index.php?option=com_listing&view=catlist&Itemid=134
2. index.php?option=com_listing&view=catlist&Itemid=135

according to Itemid i am retriving the parameter values and hence getting different data on the same link on different itemid but when i am accessing above menu links in SEF then it is creatiing the same url as "catlist.html" .I am using the SH404 Component for SEF 
on the url catlist.html it is showing only one type of data means itemid is coming same for both of the urls and also the url should be blog.html and catelog.html since the alisa
of those items are blog(for Itemid 134) and catelog(Item id 135).I have done lot's of surfing but not getting any results and please do mind i can not use create links of type "menu alias" because of the different parameters please help

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because you do not have unique title aliases in your menu items. When you have SEF URLs turned off, you have the itemid as part of the query string so Joomla knows which menu item to use to pull the parameters.

When you turn on SEF URLs, there is no query string so Joomla has to use the title alias catlist.html to figure out which menu item to use. Since it has 2 menus with the same alias, it just uses the first one that is returned in the query since there is no other way to tell them apart. Change the title alias of one of the menu items to catlist2 and you will have 2 unique URLs that both show what you want.